# How to edit/open Google Sheet using API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, curl, google-api, google-oauth

I'm using API to get access_token and now I need to open Google Sheet.

I'm sending  "Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AV...." together with link: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/[DocumentFileID]/edit" and I get HTML document back (~200kb). I'm using libcurl for that.

The problem is - missing are some css and js files and I see document just partially. Is there any way to open/edit Google Sheet using API?

I know for the option to just open [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/[DocumentFileID]/edit](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/%5BDocumentFileID%5D/edit) in the new browser tab, but in that case I need to manually login to Google and that's what I try to avoid, because I want to use API to login and to open/edit a Sheet.

I also know for the option to share a document but I also try to avoid that. I'm writing application to customers who can access they own documents once they confirmed API usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood what the google sheets api can do

> The Google Sheets API is a RESTful interface that lets you read and modify a spreadsheet's data.

It gives you access to the data, it does not allow you to open the google sheets web application.  Your going to have to code your own google sheets type app if you want users to open sheets directly.

Comment: If you are logged into Google and if you know the documentID, you can directly open the document. I want to do the same using API, is that possible?

Comment: no it is not. Thats not what the api is for.

Comment: I understand. Too bad.

Comment: Linda, I added openid into scope, when using oAuth2 and it seems it works, I'm logged into Google and I can veiw documents. Is that something expected?

Comment: If yes, how to use id_token? I know how to get new id_token after expiration, but can not figure out how to use new fresh id_token to authenticate again (after user logged off).

Comment: open id is signin.  its not the same thing as oauth2,  id tokens cant be refreshed you need to login the user again for signin.

Comment: Each time I call https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token/client_id=[ClientId]&client_secret=[clientSecret]&refresh_token=[refreshToken]&grant_type=refresh_token
I get new, fresh "id_token" (together with "access_token" and some other values).
When I check "id_token" on https://jwt.io, I see it have new expiration time, which means, it is new id_token. What is use of this new, fresh id_token if it can not be used to signin, please?

Comment: The id token denotes to your application that its signed in.   A user has signed in to your application using their google account.

Comment: OK thanks, I will signin user again on same way as first time with scope=openid.
Please tell me how to check is the user signed?

Comment: you have an id token the user is signed in to your application.

Comment: I have id_token but user logged of in the meantime. How to check is the user still logged or not?